# I already have a html page and I want to upload it into squarespace and also want to make it as a squarespace page

Tags: html, squarespace

I designed a html page on my machine. I need to upload it to squarespace. but it seems there is no option to do that. How can I do this?

Comment: Squarespace isn't just HTML, you'd have to make a squarespace template http://developers.squarespace.com/template-overview/

Comment: The page shows nothing.

Comment: Clearly the URL changed, http://developers.squarespace.com/template-configuration/